TV Show with teens (boy and girl) held hostage in mansion, trying to escape by train
The show was in English and probably American and shot in the US. I watched this show about 3-5 years ago.
There was a boy and a girl (both teenagers to my recollection) who were held captive in a room in a huge mansion.
The mansion looked pretty lively and beautiful. It had numerous windows and a huge garden in front of it.
I think I remember an underground room in the mansion through which they escaped. It probably housed the injections of the girl. In one episode I remember both of them escaping through this underground room when they injected the guard with the same injection.(It had some kind of instantaneous effect)
The girl, blonde as I recall, is medicated with injections daily (I think). They try to escape on a train that comes at certain intervals. The train was extremely important and was probably the only way to escape.

Was this a series or a single episode in a series?

Also, please don't repost existing closed questions. Instead edit the existing question into an acceptable standard.

What kind of "train"...this seems rather strange.

@Paulie_D It was a series definitely. The train was probably a cargo train (nothing strange). They tried to slow it down with some kind of levers that were present there and then tried to jumped on it.

I have deleted the previous version of this question, since this one is superior. However, please refrain from just reposting closed questions. Rather improve the existing question and adhere to the proper workflow of reopening next time.
